# Mythbuntu Public Samba Shares

Tags: networking, permissions, samba, mythbuntu, mythtv

I have installed Mythbuntu 14.04 and have MythTV running.  I am trying to access the Videos and other Samba shares from my Windows 8.1 workstation and get an `"Access Denied"` when I try.  When I type in Start -> Run -> `\\192.168.1.5`  a box pops up indicating it cannot be accessed. I also tried from CMD prompt issuing net view `\\192.168.1.5` and again get access denied.  Same access denied error if I use net use `* \\192.168.1.5\videos`.

My Windows 8.1 machine is a member of a domain, and that domain name does not match the workgroup defined on Mythbuntu.  Typically I have not seen this matter?

Below is the smb.conf file on the Ubuntu machine:

```
[global]
workgroup = MSHOME
server string = %h server (Samba, Mythbuntu)
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
syslog = 0
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
dns proxy = no
security = share
# security = user

[recordings]
comment = TV Recordings
path = /var/lib/mythtv/recordings
public = yes
writable = no
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
force user = nobody
force group = nogroup

[videos]
comment = Videos
path = /var/lib/mythtv/videos
public = yes
writable = yes
create mask = 0660
directory mask = 0770
force user = mythtv
force group = mythtv

[music]
comment = Music
path = /var/lib/mythtv/music
public = yes
writable = yes
create mask = 0660
directory mask = 0770
force user = mythtv
force group = mythtv

[pictures]
comment = Pictures
path = /var/lib/mythtv/pictures
public = yes
writable = yes
create mask = 0660
directory mask = 0770
force user = mythtv
force group = mythtv
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I needed to add a samba password to the mythtv account.

You can do this at the command line:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a mythtv
```

then follow the direction to enter a password

```
sudo restart smbd
sudo restart nmbd
```